# AppSync: How set header in response?

Tags: cookies, setcookie, aws-appsync

I want to authorize the user through http only cookies.

I want to set header in the AppSync response as example "Set-Cookie": "cookie=cookie; HttpOnly"

in "Configure the response mapping template" I have `$util.toJson($context.result)`

How can I do that?

Comment: At the moment you cannot set the response headers on a GraphQL query or mutation. Can you explain what your use case is?

Comment: Oh sure, I want to use httpOnly cookie with appsync, for this I need to set them, for it I want set header "Set-Cookie"

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I need the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Appsync doesn't allow you to pass the request cookie header to a lambda.  You can pass other headers like authorize or x-api-key or cookies but cookie seems to get stripped from the event.  I haven't found anything in the documentation about this behavior but from observation, this is what is happening currently.  You will need to pass your auth data in another header.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible through `$util.http.addResponseHeader`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html#http-helpers-in-utils-http

Comment: yes but I wonder where, you can't add this to the responseTemplate right?

Comment: You can add this to any template, request or response.